# Why didn't I get the dragon scroll?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished the mission called `Discerning the Transmundane`, but I haven't gotten the dragon scroll.  I'm not sure if I messed something up (which is likely) or if that's what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Important to note that "dragon scroll" isn't an item. You need to look for "Elder Scroll" to make sure you picked it up. You'll go through a series of button presses and it drops down in this swirly circle thing. It's pretty easy to remember that you picked it up.

Answer (score 4):

[Discerning the Transmundane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), although related to the Elder Scroll, does NOT actually require you to get said scroll!

You can inscribe the blank cube and then walk out **without taking the scroll**.  You'll need to walk back to the scroll and pick it up.